# Draggable events with different durations should be of the same size like they appear in the calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have external draggable events like in [this example](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging-demo), but mine have different durations. I want to drag them into the timeGridWeek.

But I want, that you can already see the duration of each draggable event by it´s size. I want that it has the same size like when it is dragged into the calendar.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: As far as I know there is no option for this. You would have to make a feature request to the fullCalendar developers, or submit a patch to the project yourself

Comment: Thank you, I made a [feature request](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5124).

Comment: Great. But can I suggest you read the guidelines for making feature requests: https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features. I don't think your request currently contains enough detail for the developers to take it seriously. You need to give a mhcht clearer and more detailed description of what you mean, and give some examples. Right now your description is too short and could potentially be ambiguous. The more detailed and clear your proposal is, the more likely someone will be able to work on it easily